# Calculated field value won't pass through as a parameter in report

Tags: visual-studio, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that I already created in which this works. I have three parameters in my first report with a matrix. The matrix column and rows are based off of two calculated fields. The row field is called Time Summary and is basically a time range like follows (8AM-10AM,10AM - 12PM, 12PM-2PM,Etc.) The column field is just days of the week (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Etc.) They were both calculated by a field called 'CreatedDateTime'. The value column is a count of request numbers so we can see when our call center is receiving the most service requests and at which times.

I'm drilling down to a detail report that lists each request and many of the request details. I created an action on the value (count of request) textbox in my matrix report that makes it drill into the detail report. In the detail report I have the same three parameters as in my first report, but I also have parameters for the row and column fields of my matrix (Time summary and day of the week respectively). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JICgz.png)  is a screenshot of my text box properties screen in the action tab.

The problem I'm having is that when I run my matrix report and click on the value that I want to drill into, it will drill into the detail report and update the parameter values for the three that are also in my matrix report, but it won't update the parameters for the values in which I selected in my matrix.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSrDf.png) is another screenshot of what happens when I select a value in my matrix and it drills into the detail report. I have the calculated fields in my detail report too and it filters the main data set based off of the Day parameter and Time Summary parameter. I made a report yesterday very similarly and it worked. I can't figure out why it I can't get this report to work. I'm almost positive it has to do with how I have my parameters defined in my detail report or something with the text box properties and the action. Any help in figuring this out would be appreciated.

Comment: try removing the available values and default values from the time summary and day parameters. If this works, you can either leave it as-is or if you really need available values set, then check that the passed in value matches exactly what is in the Value property of the available list.

Comment: Initially check the time summary parameter available values list by opening the dropdown. After that remove the available values from the parameter. Now the parameter value is shown on a simple textbox. Check if your parameter value match any value from the available values dataset?

Comment: @AlanSchofield  you guys were spot on. It was the available values and I got them fixed. I do need the available values, but I have it running properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @niktrs ^^^^^^^